# Read file with streams

Tags: c++, stream

I want to read file from byte to byte. But my program breaks on the first `while`

```
 ifstream infile("new.pdf",ifstream::binary);
 ofstream outfile("file.pdf",ofstream::binary);
 char *c;
 while(infile.read(c,sizeof(char)))
 {
    mpz_t M;
    mpz_t K;
    mpz_init2(M,10);
    mpz_set_ui(M,(int)c);
    mpz_init2(K,10);
    mpz_powm(K,M,e,n);
    char *x;
    mpz_get_str(x,10,K);
    outfile.write(x,sizeof(char));
 }

 infile.close();
 outfile.close();
 system("pause");
 infile.open("file.pdf",ifstream::binary);
 outfile.open("newt.pdf",ofstream::binary);
 while(infile.read(c,sizeof(char)))
 {
    mpz_t C;
    mpz_t K;
    mpz_init2(K,10);
    mpz_init2(C,10);
    int x=(int)c;
    mpz_set_ui(K,x);
    mpz_powm(C,K,d,n);
    char *s;
    mpz_get_str(s,10,C);
    outfile.write(s,sizeof(char));
  }
 infile.close();
 outfile.close();
```

What's the problem?

I need to ecnrypt file and then encrypt it.
So I decided to read byte from input file, ecnrypt it and the write to another file.

Comment: You need to more clearly state what the program is doing, why it is wrong, and what you would like it to be doing.

Comment: I noticed that you are using GMP. Should you not set the value of K in the first while loop using something like mpz_set(K, mpz_t op)?

Comment: It's not nessary. It works without it. I've tested it in program without files.

Comment: I think your use of char* is wrong. Try changing char* c to char c and refer to it as &c when calling read.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing an uninitialized pointer into the read function, this is undefined behavior.

```
char *c;  // this points off in space or who knows where
while(infile.read(c,sizeof(char))) // therefore, this is undefined behavior
```

Try this:

```
char c;
while(infile.read(&c,sizeof(char)))
```

Comment: It passed this line but then breaks on `outfile.write`

Answer (score 0):

it returns the stream, so before the first while check if the stream is good by using ifstream::good() . Also you might need to use the same function to check end of file.

Comment: `istream::read` checks the stream status before attempting input.